# redirect to "MY cart" page instead of "Checkout" page after registration in magento

Tags: magento, registration, coupon

we provide coupon codes for only Registered customers.

so what we did is when a guest applied a coupon code it will display a message

"please register" , but when guest succesfully registered , its redirecting to "checkout" page instead of

"My Cart" page. i want to redirect to "My cart" page after registration.

please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the **Account Controller**, find the function **_welcomeCustomer()**

Just add the code below before the line **return $successUrl;**

```
 $successUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'checkout/cart/';
```

Comment: thanks a lot for reply, it worked fine.

along with that  what i  need is some customers might have already registered.

so if those customers will login using email and password.

but after cusomer logged-in , he is redirecting to "my account" page.

what  i need is if "customer" registered than he also should re direct to "my cart/shopping cart" page.

can you please help

Comment: can you please help for redirect "Registration " to "shopping cart" page

Comment: in another site its not working ? can you please help ?